# PHP: Quiz answers were showing up until I pressed the next button one too many times

Tags: php, mysqli, radio-button

I'm trying to make my quiz work. The problem that I'm having is that innitially when I got my code to work I could see my sql table's content alongside my radiobuttons, four answers sorted by the same id (qid).

After I pressed the next button one too many times, I couldnt see anything on the page, I've even tried to refresh my browser several times. How can I see my questions again on my page? And how do I prevent this from happening again? I am using Google Chrome, but I've already tried it on Firefox and Internet Explorer but nothing works.

**PHP/HTML**

```
<?php

$localhost = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$connect = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password) or die ("Kunde inte koppla");
mysqli_select_db($connect, 'wildfire');

session_start();
$qid = isset($_SESSION['qid']) ? $_SESSION['qid']+1 : 1;
$_SESSION['qid'] = $qid;

ob_start();

echo "<form>";
$sql1 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM question where qid ='$qid'");

while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1))
    echo "<input type='radio' name='answer1' value='{$row1['Point']}'>{$row1['answer']}<br>";

echo "<input type='submit' name='forward' value='next'>";
echo "</form>";


$output = ob_get_clean();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body> 
        <?php echo $output; ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Using only php and html, makes user feel the website too old style. Use jquery and ajax, make it more user friendly. And not only that, refreshing the pages too many times, affects your bandwidth.

Comment: But how do I make this work, I'd rather not use AJAX since I'm not so familliar with it? What is weird is that this was working innitially, I'm pretty sure I'm not imagining things.

Comment: use button outside the loop

Comment: @devpro I just tried that, and nothing happens

Comment: Try this on ist line of page and check what happend:    session_start();
$qid = isset($_SESSION['qid']) ? $_SESSION['qid']+1 : 1;
$_SESSION['qid'] = $qid; print_r($_SESSION);exit;

Comment: @devpro All it does is print out an array with a number (on my page it gives me the number 68). Maybe if I could cap it out to a specific number (example number eight) it would only show eight answers with the specific qid, does that sound like a viable idea?

Comment: @PHPScrub: it means your session variable is working fine... now try my answer that i have shared

Comment: Done, I've sent a comment. @devpro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?
$localhost = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$connect = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password) or die ("Kunde inte koppla");
mysqli_select_db($connect, 'wildfire');

$qid = (!isset($_POST['qid']) && intval($_POST['qid']) == 0) ? 1 : $_POST['qid']+1;

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body> 
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="qid" value="<?=$qid?>">
            <?php
                $sql1 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM question where qid =".intval($qid));
                while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1)){
                ?>
                <input type='radio' name='answer1' value="<?php echo $row1['Point'];?>"><?php echo $row1['answer'];?><br>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            <input type='submit' name='forward' value='next'>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

**What Change?**

I am using `$_POST` for qid ID instead of `SESSION` because when you refresh the page you need to unset session value, so store qid into `$_POST` instead of `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Hmm. I get four errors on the rows inside the form. "undefined variables" and and expecting more parameters, etc.. But they have been defined, which is really weird.

Comment: @PHPScrub: i have updated, using <?php echo instead of <?=

Comment: Alright, I get no errors now. But I still get the same result that I got prior to asking this question. I need to make the first eight questions viewable again.

Comment: @PHPScrub: as per code only one question will display against the $qid right.. and when u move forward $qid will change as +1 and question also be changed... i am right?

Comment: ohh, i see, actually when u refresh the page, you session is set as previous value. u need to unset the session for getting ist question..

Comment: @PHPScrub: i have updated my answer and used $_POST value instead of session.

Comment: The session isnt unset for some reason. Initially when I pressed next more than eight times (amount of qid in database) it shows nothing which is fine. But when I refresh the page it didnt show me the first question again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99285/discussion-between-devpro-and-php-scrub).